# How to implement custom access to node revisions?

Tags: 8, nodes

I want to implement a custom access check in Drupal 8, where users assigned to the node field node-owner have view/edit and **revisions** view/edit permissions for this specific node.

I have implemented it for node view/edit using the node access system with `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_grants()`. But I cannot find how to implement it for the node revisions, since the access check performed in `NodeRevisionAccessCheck` takes into account only the 'view revisions' and 'revert revisions' role permissions and I cannot see a relevant hook.

Should I do **custom access checking on routes** as described here?
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes

And if yes, how do I implement the route check and fetch the current node?

Comment: what's exactly url you want check access?

Comment: @Jonh /node/%/revisions/%/view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, node revision does not have hook implement for check access. So you need other way to resolved your problem. My way is [alter existing services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services). Just following document, there is file **my_module/src/MyModuleServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * Class MyModuleServiceProvider.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule
 */
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('access_check.node.revision');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\my_module\Access\MyModuleNodeRevisionAccessCheck');
    $definition->setArguments(
      [
        new Reference('entity.manager'),
      ]
    );
  }

}
```

After alter **access_check.node.revision** service. I'll define new class check access view node revision with extend class NodeRevisionAccessCheck and override method access like this. File **src/Access/MyModuleNodeRevisionAccessCheck**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\node\Access\NodeRevisionAccessCheck;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

/**
 * Provides an access checker for node revisions.
 *
 * @ingroup node_access
 */
class MyModuleNodeRevisionAccessCheck extends NodeRevisionAccessCheck {

  public function access(Route $route, AccountInterface $account, $node_revision = NULL, NodeInterface $node = NULL) {
    if ($node_revision) {
      $node = $this->nodeStorage->loadRevision($node_revision);
    }
    $operation = $route->getRequirement('_access_node_revision');
    // You can override logic check access here or provide a new hook.
  }

}
```

Comment: Worked as a charm. Actually I overrid the **checkAccess** method of the **NodeRevisionAccessCheck** class.

Comment: Yes, If you understand about logic of the method **checkAcesss**, you can override it. If no, better override method acess, just procces logic of you and return before line return AccessResult::allowedIf($node && $this->checkAccess($node, $account, $operation))->cachePerPermissions()->addCacheableDependency($node);